# Parsing Multiple DateTimes in USQL

Tags: u-sql

So the file I am extracting has multiple instances of two different starting time formats. One start time is in zulu (UTC) format and another is in a standard dateTime format. So when I create a SELECT they both have to pass through it.

An example of my UTC startingTime is `2011-01-02T00:03:04.123Z`

An example of a standard startingTime is `2011-Jan-20 01:15:37.000941 EST`

I need some sort of dateTime.Parse that can handle them both and return it to me in the same style the second one `2011-Jan-20 01:15:37.000941 EST` is in.

Currently I am using `DateTime.Parse(StartingTime).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff) As StartingTime"`

This works for Parsing the UTC time format but gives me an error when trying to Parse the other.

Any ideas?

Even if I don't get it to return to me exactly like this one `2011-Jan-20 01:15:37.000941 EST` I'll take something that shows three figures of milli seconds ex: `2011-Jan-20 01:15:37.941 EST` which is what my code does now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have this kind of date you can try this. 
You can add more types on the IF statement!

```
DECLARE @func Func<string,string> = (s) => {

                                    DateTime d;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out d))
                                    {
                                        TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

                                        d = DateTime.SpecifyKind(d, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

                                        DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(d, cstZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

                                        return cstTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff EST");
                                    }
                                    return s;
};

@data = 
    SELECT data FROM 
        ( VALUES
        ("2011-01-02T00:03:04.123Z")
        ,("2011-Jan-20 01:15:37.000941 EST")

        ) AS T(data);


@result =
    SELECT @func(data) AS data FROM @data;

OUTPUT @result
TO "/test.txt"
USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me too!